# Why does passing $null to a parameter with AllowNull() result in an error?

Tags: powershell, parameters, nullable

Consider the following code:

```
function Test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [AllowNull()]
        [String]
        $ComputerName
    ) 
    process{}
}

Test -ComputerName $null
```

Based on [the official documentation for `AllowNull`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx) I was expecting that `$ComputerName` could either be `[string]` or `$null`.  However, running the above code results in the following error:

> [14,24: Test] Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ComputerName' because it is an empty 
>   string.

Why doesn't passing $null for `$ComputerName` work in this case?

Comment: I can't give you a definitive explanation, but to me it looks like `$null` is cast to an empty string, due to the parameter type, and thus isn't covered by the validation attribute anymore. Using `AllowEmptyString()` instead works. I'd consider this a documentation bug.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45720150/1404637)

Answer (score 7):

`$null`, when converted to [string], return empty string not `$null`:

```
[string]$null -eq $null # False
[string]$null -eq [string]::Empty # True
```

If you want to pass `$null` for [string] parameter you should use `[NullString]::Value`:

```
[string][NullString]::Value -eq $null # True
Test -ComputerName ([NullString]::Value)
```

Comment: Just one warning, tihs doesnt work on 2.0 as far as i could say

Answer (score 3):

You also need to add the `[AllowEmptyString()]` attribute if you plan on allowing nulls *and* empty strings.

```
function Test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [AllowNull()]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [String]
        $ComputerName
    ) 
    process{}
}

Test -ComputerName $null
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted, when cast to a [string], $null becomes an empty string (""). To avoid this, one option is to type the param as an object - then in the body test first for $null, then check that $MyParam.GetType().Name is "String".